# Laravel 5.3 - Download rendered code as a HTML

Tags: php, html, file, laravel-5, download

my goal is to download a rendered view in my controller. 
Looks like this:

```
$view = view('/´my/view', ['data' => $data])->render();
```

now the `$view` variable contains all the rendered code I want to download as a `.html` file

I've tried this to download the variable as a file:

```
 $headers = ['Content-type: text/html'];
 return response()->download($view, 'view.html', $headers);
```

But this returns "File does not exists". 
And yes, the file does not exists. Is it possible to download it directly?

Sorry for my bad english.

Thanks for any help!

---

Solution:

```
header("Content-type: text/html");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='view.html'");
return $view;
```

Comment: Got it to work now. I will put my answer in the question

Comment: Thanks, that's instructive.